# Pipe the output of eval/source in fish shell

Tags: eval, file-descriptor, io-redirection, fish

I want to pipe the output of `eval` to a file. That works as expected if the command execution is successful:

```sh
eval ls > log.txt 2>&1
cat log.txt # Documents Desktop
```

It also works if the command is not successful

```sh
eval rm Desktop > log.txt 2>&1
cat log.txt # rm: cannot remove 'Desktop': Is a directory
```

However, I do not manage to redirect stderr if the command does not exist

```sh
eval abcde > log.txt 2>&1 # fish: Unknown command abcde
cat log.txt # (empty)
```

How can I redirect also the output of the third case to a log file?

---

Something that works with `source` would also be very much appreciated:

```sh
echo abcde | source > log.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Why are you using `eval`? Your examples don't require it. You can also test if a command exists by doing `if command -sq abcde`,

Comment: In my real example, I am doing `eval $argv` inside a function. That is why I need `eval` (alternatively, `source`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, I do not manage to redirect stderr if the command does not exist

That's because the output is not coming from `eval` or the command, it's coming from your command-not-found handler.

Try checking if the command exists before you try to execute it. If you absolutely can't, it's technically possible to silence the command-not-found error entirely by redefining `__fish_command_not_found_handler`:

```
function __fish_command_not_found_handler; end
```

You'd have to handle moving it back afterwards via `functions --copy`:

```
functions --copy __fish_command_not_found_handler oldcnf
```

Overall I don't recommend any of this and suspect you might be overusing `eval`.

> Something that works with source would also be very much appreciated:

That's what eval is for, quite literally. Up to the upcoming 3.1 release eval is a function that's just `source` with some support code that mostly boils down to handling these redirections.

Comment: That works. I will check whether the command exists before using eval. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should eval if command exists, this is possible with

```
test -f (whereis -b command | awk '{print $2}')
```

`whereis -b` will to search for the binaries for the `command` in your system

`awk` filter the output to only show the first result

`test -f` going to verify if the file exists

If the command exist, it return `status 0`. So to finish you can write it like

```
test -f (whereis -b abcde | awk '{print $2}') && abcde > log.txt 2>&1
```

---

Also can use this form

```
test (whereis -b abcde | awk '{print $2}') != '' && abcde > log.txt 2>&1
```